# Swift/UIKit How to create a CollectionView that peeks the prev/next cells and snaps to center?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a UICollectionView that displays some cards, one a time. What I would like to do is have something like the attached image, where the current card stays in the center but the Collection View previews part of the previous and next cells. Playing with cell size, insets and line spacing breaks scrolling because the cells gradually become less and less centred. Do you have any tips on how to achieve this behaviour?
[collectionview with peeking cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh0lR.png)

Comment: collection views compositional layout has a snapping behavior, look into this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1uXXVUu43o

Comment: Do you want **paging** (scroll one cell at a time)? Or, do you want normal scrolling, with "snap to center" when deceleration ends?